# Newline character at the end of bulk index Elasticsearch python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to bulk update using python elasticsearch. I have a list containing dictionary of metadata (_id, _type, _doc) follow by dictionary of actual data (the data will be in _source) repeatedly.

I am experiencing some missing documents when bulk index more than 50000 documents. Follow this guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/bulk.html .

Do I need to add '\n' character at the end of each object? How can I add '
\n' when all my element in list is dictionary? What is the correct format? Thank you

Comment: the new line is only for raw HTTP exchanges. The python client simply uses a list and will add the newline character when building the HTTP request.